# Help in understanding a logic puzzle

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

[Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications, 8e, by Rosen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1260091996) solves the following logic puzzle:

> As a reward for saving his daughter from pirates, the King has given
> you the opportunity to win a treasure hidden inside one of three
> trunks. The two trunks that do not hold the treasure are empty. To
> win, you must select the correct trunk. Trunks 1 and 2 are each
> inscribed with the message "This trunk is empty," and Trunk 3 is
> inscribed with the message "The treasure is in Trunk 2." The Queen,
> who never lies, tells you that only one of these inscriptions is true,
> while the other two are wrong. Which trunk should you select to win?

The solution provided is as follows (symbols changed for easier readability):

```
p: Treasure is in Trunk 1
q: Treasure is in Trunk 2
  
... the inscriptions on Trunk 1, Trunk 2, and Trunk 3, are ¬p, ¬q, and q. 

The Queen's statement can be translated to:  
    (¬p ∧ ¬(¬q) ∧ ¬q) ∨ (¬(¬p) ∧ ¬q ∧ ¬q) ∨ (¬(¬p) ∧ ¬(¬q) ∧ q))
```

The final solution is:

> the inscription on Trunk 2 is the only true one

I am having tough time understanding the logical representation of the Queen's statement.  Why is it of type `(A) ∨ (B) ∨ (C)`?  Furthermore, why is the "Treasure is in Trunk 3" proposition not showing at all?  After all the message on Trunk 1 and/or Trunk 2 could be false.

---

**Addendum**
`"the inscription on Trunk 2 is the only true one"` implies that the treasure is either in Trunk 1 or Trunk 3.  It appears to me that we have insufficient information from the problem to definitely say whether the treasure is in Trunk 1 or in Trunk 3.  Is that correct?

Comment: Do you agree with the translations of the inscriptions on the trunks?

Comment: @saulspatz there is no confusion regarding the inscriptions on the trunks.  I am having trouble understanding the Queen's statement.

Comment: Technically the queen's statement should be XORs,  in that exactly one is true.  However, since all 3 of the statements are mutually exclusive, as soon as one is true that makes the other two false.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 2):

The queen says that exactly one statement is true.  That means that one of the statements is true and the other two are false.

Let the statements be $x,y,z$  If $x$ is the only true one, we have $$x\land\lnot y\land\lnot z$$ Similarly, if $y$ is the only true one, we have
$$
\lnot x\land y\land\lnot z
$$
and if $z$ is the only true one, you know what to do.  Now the queen says that one of these cases obtains, which means that the disjunction of them holds.

Does this explain it?  If not, please tell me how far you get before you have trouble.

BTW: The treasure must be in trunk $1$, not trunk $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Trunk 1 is asserting $\lnot p$ Trunk 2 is asserting $\lnot q$.  Trunk 3 is asserting $q$.

Now, the queen is saying one of these statements is true, the other two are false.  This is possible if 1 is true and 2/3 are false,  2 is true and 1/3 are false, or 3 is true and 1/2 are false
THe first of these is done by connecting 1 to the neggations of 2 and 3 with "ands"

$$\lnot p \land\lnot(\lnot(q))\land \lnot q$$

That's why that's the first of the ors.
The second is the case where only the middle statement is true and the other two are false, and the third is the third statement is true and the first 2 are false.

Putting together them with ors says at least 1 is true.  You get exactly one is true because it is impossible for more than one to be true at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

> It appears to me that we have insufficient information from the problem to definitely say whether the treasure is in Trunk 1 or in Trunk 3. Is that correct?

We have two pieces of useful information to find the solution:

1. A trunk can only either be empty or have the treasure.
2. Since Trunk 2 is telling the truth, the other two *have to be* false. Trunk 1 says "This trunk is empty", and this *has to be* false.

Therefore, Trunk 1 has the treasure.